# ORA-10400 error in PL/SQL, cannot auto generate tran_no field in table using procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

T_Acc_Details is a table for storing the account number details of a person with the given fields.

```
create table T_Acc_Details(
  acc_no number(5) primary key,
  acc_holder_name varchar2(50),
  acc_type varchar2(5) check (acc_type in ('SB', 'CA', 'FD')),
  opening_date date,
  balance_amt number(10,2)
)
```

I have also inputted values into the field like the following:

```
insert into T_Acc_Details values(10000, 'A', 'SB', to_date('23/11/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 1000.2);
```

Secondly, I created the Transaction details table in which the values are to be inserted on the basis of it being deposit or withdrawal. The table query is as follows:

```
create table T_Tran_Details(
  tran_no number(5) primary key not null,
  acc_no number(5),
  tran_type varchar2(5) check (tran_type in ('w', 'd')),
  transaction_date date,
  amount number(10,2),
  foreign key(acc_no) references T_Acc_Details(acc_no)
)
```

Furthur, this is my procedure. Here, I have taken acc_no, amount, tran_type as paramters and taken current balance from balance amount and tran_no as variables. I am trying to write the logic for deposit portion. Also, autogenerating value for tran_no.

```
create or replace procedure pr_updateBal(
p_acc_no T_Acc_Details.Acc_No%type,
p_amount T_Tran_Details.Amount%type,
p_tran_type T_Tran_Details.Tran_Type%type
) is
p_curr_bal T_Acc_Details.Balance_Amt%type;
p_tran_no T_Tran_Details.Tran_No%type;
begin
  select max(nvl(tran_no,0)+1) into p_tran_no from T_Tran_Details;
  select T_Acc_Details.Balance_Amt into p_curr_bal from T_Acc_Details where T_Acc_Details.Acc_No = p_acc_no;
  if(p_tran_type = 'd') then
    p_curr_bal := p_curr_bal + p_amount;
    insert into T_Tran_Details(tran_no, acc_no, tran_type, transaction_date, amount) 
    values (p_tran_no, p_acc_no, p_tran_type, to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YY'), p_amount);
    update T_Acc_Details
    set T_Acc_Details.Balance_Amt = p_curr_bal;
    dbms_output.put_line('Amount deposited!');
  end if;
end pr_updateBal;
```

As soon as I try to test the code and run, the insert into T_Tran_Details(.. gives rise to this error. How are the values even null? I have taken tran_no as primary key.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tmf8.jpg)

Comment: This is working fin for me - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=61851374a34344434776f8059bea7ba6
Can you please share how you are testing this?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I am right-clicking on the procedure and testing it. Inserting the values as 10000, 2345, d for the parameters. As soon as I run it, I get that error.

Comment: funny thing is that this code was working fine around 5 hours ago, now it doesn't

Comment: I think you are getting this error because your T_Tran_Details table is empty. So nothing to select into variable p_tran_no. And when it is being used in the Insert statement, You are getting a Null insertion error.

Comment: Once you filled up your table It will work perfectly - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a2f70ddbc70273ef076eb4af8e4665bb

Comment: thank you, @AnkitBajpai! It works but what if I wanted to add a new row? I would not be able to do it, right?

Comment: No. You can't. You have to add 1 row at least to make it work.

Comment: Use a SEQUENCE to populate `tran_no` column, or else define it as an IDENTITY column.  The approach in your question is well-established **bad practice** which not only is over-complicated, but also it does not scale and it is unsafe in a multi-user environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found your problem, so this line:

```
select max(nvl(tran_no,0)+1) into p_tran_no from T_Tran_Details;
```

generates a null value bcs your table is empty, when u simply write:

```
Select max(nvl(tran_no,0)+1) max from T_Tran_Details;
```

u get a null value in the max column.

To generate new tran_no try using a sequence or like this:

```
for i in (select max(tran_no) max from T_Tran_Details) loop
   if i.max is null then p_tran_no:=0;
   else p_tran_no:=i.max +1;
end if;
end loop;
```

So your whole code would look like this:

```
create or replace procedure pr_updateBal(
            p_acc_no T_Acc_Details.Acc_No%type,
            p_amount T_Tran_Details.Amount%type,
            p_tran_type T_Tran_Details.Tran_Type%type
) 
is
p_curr_bal T_Acc_Details.Balance_Amt%type;
p_tran_no T_Tran_Details.Tran_No%type;
begin


 for i in (select max(tran_no) max from T_Tran_Details) loop
      if i.max is null then p_tran_no:=0;
      else p_tran_no:=i.max+1;
    end if;
 end loop;

  select T_Acc_Details.Balance_Amt into p_curr_bal from T_Acc_Details 
   where  T_Acc_Details.Acc_No = p_acc_no;

 if(p_tran_type = 'd') then
       p_curr_bal := p_curr_bal + p_amount;
 insert into T_Tran_Details(tran_no, acc_no, tran_type, transaction_date, amount) 
values (p_tran_no, p_acc_no, p_tran_type, to_date(sysdate,'DD/MM/YY'), p_amount);
update T_Acc_Details
set T_Acc_Details.Balance_Amt = p_curr_bal;
dbms_output.put_line('Amount deposited!');
end if;
end pr_updateBal;
```